Sorting rows of a matrix by column values in Power BI
I've created a matrix in Power BI similar to the one below. The entries are a calculated field. I can sort the rows by the "Total" column and the "Name" column by clicking on the arrows that appear in the "Name" cell and the "Total" cell. However, there are no arrows for the columns "2021", "2022", and "2023". Is there any way to sort by the columns "2021", "2022", and "2023"?

